# Conditional expectation uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $ \xi $ $ \sim \operatorname{Uniform}[0, 1]$ ( continuous).

I need to find the meaning of an expression $ \mathbb{E}(\xi | \xi^2) $.

When we calc $ \mathbb{E}(\xi^2 | \xi) = \xi^2$ because $\xi^2$ sigma measurable $\xi$.

But how to calc in my case?

Comment: $\xi \geq 0$, therefore knowing $\xi^2$ is the same as knowing $\xi$. I'd expect the result to be $\xi$. :)

Comment: @Andrew and what?

Comment: Take the usual, real valued $\sqrt \cdot $ function. It's continuous, therefore measurable. Then note that $\xi = \sqrt\cdot \circ \xi^2 $ (here we use that $\xi \geq 0$). All this implies that $\mathbb{E}(\xi | \xi^2) = \xi$.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Andrew](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/94959/andrew) in the comments, $\xi$ is a function of $\xi^2$. Indeed, since $\xi$ takes non-negative values, 
$$
\xi=\left\lvert \xi\right\rvert=\sqrt{\xi^2}.
$$
Consequently, $\mathbb{E}\left(\xi | \xi^2\right)=\xi$.